# How to get /rgbdslam/batch_clouds data

Tags: ros, python, roslaunch, rgbdslam-v2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I just installed rgbdslam v2 on my 12.04 unbuntu. I subscribed to the /rgbdslam/batch_clouds topic as specified on the rgbdslam v2 github page. I included it in the launch file of my package. However I see that there is no data being published to the topic when I roslaunch the sample launch files and rostopic hz /rgbdslam/batch_clouds. On the rgbdslam v2 github website, it says I need to "command it" to publish to the topic, but the website does not specify how. If anyone knows how to do this, could you please explain to me how?

Thank you,
Evan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187596/how-to-get-/rgbdslam/batch_clouds-data/) by [ephibbs](https://answers.ros.org/users/19830/ephibbs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2014-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found in the launch config file in rgbdslam v2 that I needed to include some parameters in my launch file and send the service call: rosservice /rgbdslam/ros_ui send_all. However, still no data is being published to the batch_clouds topic. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me.

---

Originally posted by [ephibbs](https://answers.ros.org/users/19830/ephibbs/) with karma: 16 on 2014-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0